# Using "display: table-cell" is there a way of getting the "colspan" functionality?

Tags: css

Using `display: table-cell` is there a way of getting the `colspan` functionality, which is available when using real table cells?

In particular I need some "cells" to span multiple columns.

Real tables are not a possibility as I am using a *form per row* layout, which won't validate as a real table.

Comment: Set width accordingly?

Comment: @BenM the point of using "display: table-cell" is so that the widths adjust to the size of the content.

Comment: a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css

Answer (score 67, accepted):

No you cannot add colspan or rowspan to display:table-cell. It is one of the limitations in table-cell feature!

You can check the limitations in this reference link

http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout

If you want to bring the COLSPAN feature into table-cell, then you have to use table-row-group and table-caption feature as follows

```
display: table-caption
```

and

```
table-row-group;
```

Check this fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQY4/

Comment: This is a good workaround, but cannot be applied for arbitrary rows (say, 2nd or 5th) in the table. In such a case, `display: table` or an inline table can do the trick.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wo40ev18/3/

Comment: Kudos for fiddle and Answer should go to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9851624/383904

Comment: what if i want caption below the table

Comment: .caption {border:1px solid grey; caption-side: bottom; display: table-caption; text-align: center; } to display caption below