# CSS Tables Colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

Alright i am trying not to use HTML tables at all possible now a days. But i am using CSS tables but i am wondering if there is an equivalent of colspan in CSS tables.

I have this code

```
#fleetTable{display: table;width: 360px;margin: 0 auto;margin-top: 20px;font-size:.875em;float:left;}
    .fleetRow{display: table-row;}
    .fleetCell{display: table-cell;}
```

And this HTML

```
<div id="fleetTable">
    <div class="fleetRow textright">
        <div class="fleetCell">Headline</div> <!-- I would like this to span both columns below but be centered -->
    </div>
    <div class="fleetRow textright">
        <div class="fleetCel;">Cell1</div>
        <div class="fleetCell">Cell2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What selector would you use here to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [table-cell - some kind of colspan?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851582/table-cell-some-kind-of-colspan)

Comment: Don't go overboard.  It's totally OK to use tables to lay out tabular data.  If what you have really is a table of data, then for heaven's sake use a table.  Don't use tables to do *page* layout.

Comment: Yeah it was duplicate but google didnt give me that result @Quentin but thanks for the link that will work.

Comment: @IanMcLaird it is such a battle of where to use them and where to not. I was taught to use them way back when and then after learning real CSS layouts i have tried to stay away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making an obvious assumption that your header will be the first cell of the first row and which having the `.fleetCell` class. So you can select this first element using `:first-child` pseudo selector like this.

CSS

```
.fleetCell:first-child{
   text-align:center;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LvaCD/)

Comment: Interesting way of doing this. Your assumption is correct, this needs support for IE7 and IE8 uggghhhh but thanks for the answer. I really need to use pseudo elements more for things like this.