# css div disable table row colspan

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make the collapsible row colspanned to the number of columns? Or at least have the full width as of the div table? I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746061/div-table-colspan-how) but it doesn't seem to help.

You may check out the full code here in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v98ffkf4/5/).

```
<div class="div-table">
<div class="div-heading">
    <div>Head 1</div>
    <div>Head 2</div>
    <div>Head 3</div>
    <div>Head 4</div>
    <div>Head 5</div>
    <div>Head 6</div>
</div>
<div class="div-row">
    <div class="cell">col 1</div>
    <div class="cell">col 2</div>
    <div class="cell">col 3</div>
    <div class="cell">col 4</div>
    <div class="cell"><a href="#row1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="row1">col 5</a>

    </div>
    <div class="cell">col 6</div>
</div>
<div class="div-row div-row-collapsible">
    <div class="collapse text-center" id="row1">must be full width</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `<table>`?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing in another div.

```
<div>
</div>
```

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5x8wu0sc/

I only updated the html.

Answer (score 0):

The whole width available to your div containing the text "must be full width" end where the second column cell of your table should start. This seems to be aa a  consequence of the display='table' used in the main div. You can't use a colspan to enlarge over the first column as explained here : [Colspan/Rowspan for elements whose display is set to table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277661/colspan-rowspan-for-elements-whose-display-is-set-to-table-cell)

I think you have to consider using bootstrap grid system. It should give you an easy way to have table stuff well done.